# how to edit datagridview cells using a secondary textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have **form1** with `datagridview` (2 columns with 1 column id,1 column text).

I also have `"edit button"`. When i click `"edit button"`, the text column will show in textbox at **form2**.

In **form2** I have "`select button`" to edit path and `"save button"`.

How can I pass the edited text in **form2** to column datagridview in form1 by press `"save button"`.

Code Edit button in **form1** (dgv_sourcefolder is datagridview1) :

```
private void DGV_sourcefolder_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (DGV_sourcefolder.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit")
        {
            string y = "";
            int i;
            i = ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            y = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());
            DTO.data = y;
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
```

Code Select Button in form2 :

```
private void Btn_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();         
        if(fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form should be look like this.

```
public class Form2 : Form 
    {

        private DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow;
        public Form2(DataGridViewRow row) 
        {
            dataGridViewRow = row;
        }
        private void Btn_select_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
               textBox1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
            }

        }
        private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
             this.dataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value = textBox1.Text;
        }
    }
```

it main form

```
private void DGV_sourcefolder_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {          
        if (DGV_sourcefolder.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit")
        {
            string y = "";
            int i;
            i = ((DataGridView)sender).SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            y = ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(y.ToString());
            DTO.data = y;
            var row =  ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[i];
            Form2 form = new Form2(row);
            form.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried but the pop up windows show " Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at save button. I will try to fix :)

Comment: make sure this "var row =  ((DataGridView)sender).Rows[i];" should not be null object.

Answer (score 0):

Not assuming anything about the data in your data grid, you can make use of the DataGridViewCell's ParseFormattedValue method and FormatedValue property to make the text box in form2 behave just as a text box in the data grid would. This will help if you are not using string as the value type in your data grid.

```
public Form2
{
    TextBox _myTextBox; 
    public Form2()
    { ... }

    public DataGridViewCell CurrentCell {get;set;}

    protected override void OnLoad()
    {
        Assert(CurrentCell != null);
        _myTextBox = CurrentCell.FormatedValue;
    }

    public SubmitBtn_clicked(...)
    {
        try
        {
           var cellValue = CurrentCell.ParseFormattedValue(_myTextBox.Text,  
                     CurrentCell.Style, (TypeConverter)null, (TypeConverter)null);
           CurrentCell.Value = cellValue;
        }
        catch(FormatException)
        {/*user entered value that cant be parsed*/ }
        catch(ArgumentException)
        {/*_myTextBox.Text was null or cell's FormattedValueType is not string*/}
    }
}
```